# How to calculate the current month from python time.time()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the current number of month which is 3(Today is 04.03.2016). So I'm running:

```
from time import time
Ys=12*30*24*3600
Ms=Ys/12
m=(trunc(time())%Ys)/Ms
print m
```

and the result is 10.

Interestingly when I run:

```
Ds=Ms/30
d=(trunc(time())%Ms)/Ds
```

then the result is correct : 4.

Why m is not 3 but 10?

Comment: `time` does not return the number of seconds since the beginning of the year, and some month do not have 30 days.

Comment: Then why the day, hour and minute are correct?

Comment: [**`date.today()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) is the same as `date.fromtimestamp(time.time())`.

Comment: Because they are not affected by your approximate "days per month" calculation. But last year there was even a leap second so seconds should be off in your example.

Comment: Then what is the better approximation of "days per month"?

Comment: Thank you all for suggesting different approaches to get the current time, but that's not what I'm asking for. Thanks to MSeifert and Holt I know now that the problem is in the days per month approximation or Ms value. What is the best approximation of it to get the correct result?

Comment: There _isn't_ really a better approximation of days per month that you can use like that. OTOH, 30.6 can be used with an adjusted calendar that starts at March, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date#Calculation) for details.

Comment: But _please_ use the date conversion algorithms in the standard modules. It can be an interesting learning exercise to write your own, but it's not wise to use such code in a "real" program - it's too easy to get something slightly wrong, and then you have to live with your mistakes. Eg, Excel has "inherited" a [buggy leap year algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_bug) to maintain compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3.

Comment: @PM2Ring of course I'll do that, but in this case this is not about matter of choice. I wan't to develop algorithm to get the number of months from such a number obtained over peer to peer communication in a micro controller. I want to use python for checking the value only.

Comment: In that case, take a look at [Julian or Gregorian calendar from Julian day number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Julian_or_Gregorian_calendar_from_Julian_day_number); it's fairly easy to convert Epoch seconds to Julian days.

Comment: @PM 2Ring could you please suggest a complete solution to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to convert the Unix epoch time to the (UTC) Gregorian date without using any library functions. The code below only imports `time`  to verify that the calculated date is identical to that returned by `time.gmtime`.

Please beware that at 03:14:08 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038, 32-bit versions of the Unix time stamp will cease to work, as it will overflow the largest value that can be held in a signed 32-bit number. So do not attempt to call `time.gmtime` for such timestamps on a 32 bit system. Of course, the algorithm used below does not suffer from such limitations.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Convert Unix Epoch seconds to (proleptic) Gregorian date

    Algorithm by E. G. Richards, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35796786/4014959

    Python implementation by PM 2Ring 2016.03.07
'''

from time import gmtime

def epoch_seconds_to_gregorian_date(eseconds):
    # Algorithm parameters for Gregorian calendar
    y = 4716; j = 1401; m = 2; n = 12; r = 4; p = 1461 
    v = 3; u = 5; s = 153; w = 2; B = 274277; C = -38

    #Julian day, rounded
    J = int(0.5 + eseconds / 86400.0 + 2440587.5)

    f = J + j + (((4 * J + B) // 146097) * 3) // 4 + C
    e = r * f + v
    g = (e % p) // r
    h = u * g + w
    D = (h % s) // u + 1
    M = (h // s + m) % n + 1
    Y = (e // p) - y + (n + m - M) // n

    return Y, M, D

# Tests    
def test(s):
    t = gmtime(s)
    gmdate = t.tm_year, t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday
    e2gdate = epoch_seconds_to_gregorian_date(s)
    assert gmdate == e2gdate, (t, gmdate, e2gdate)
    return '%d.%d.%d' % e2gdate    

print 'hours'
for i in xrange(25):
    s = 3600 * i
    print i, test(s) 

print '\ndays'
for i in xrange(32):
    s = 86400 * i
    print i, test(s)

print '\n2 days by seconds...'
for s in xrange(86400 * 2):
    test(s)

n = 50
print '\n%d years by days...' % n
for i in xrange(365 * n):
    s = 86400 * i    
    test(s)

print 'Ok'
```

**output**

```
hours
0 1970.1.1
1 1970.1.1
2 1970.1.1
3 1970.1.1
4 1970.1.1
5 1970.1.1
6 1970.1.1
7 1970.1.1
8 1970.1.1
9 1970.1.1
10 1970.1.1
11 1970.1.1
12 1970.1.1
13 1970.1.1
14 1970.1.1
15 1970.1.1
16 1970.1.1
17 1970.1.1
18 1970.1.1
19 1970.1.1
20 1970.1.1
21 1970.1.1
22 1970.1.1
23 1970.1.1
24 1970.1.2

days
0 1970.1.1
1 1970.1.2
2 1970.1.3
3 1970.1.4
4 1970.1.5
5 1970.1.6
6 1970.1.7
7 1970.1.8
8 1970.1.9
9 1970.1.10
10 1970.1.11
11 1970.1.12
12 1970.1.13
13 1970.1.14
14 1970.1.15
15 1970.1.16
16 1970.1.17
17 1970.1.18
18 1970.1.19
19 1970.1.20
20 1970.1.21
21 1970.1.22
22 1970.1.23
23 1970.1.24
24 1970.1.25
25 1970.1.26
26 1970.1.27
27 1970.1.28
28 1970.1.29
29 1970.1.30
30 1970.1.31
31 1970.2.1

2 days by seconds...

50 years by days...
Ok
```

---

Here's an improved version that also returns hours, minutes, and seconds. This code handles fractional seconds, however, the fields of `time.struct_time` are all integers, so my `test` function cannot be used with fractional seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Convert Unix Epoch seconds to (proleptic) Gregorian date

    Algorithm by E. G. Richards, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

    See http://stackoverflow.com/q/35796786/4014959

    Python implementation by PM 2Ring 2016.03.07
'''

from time import time, gmtime
from random import randint
import sys    

def epoch_seconds_to_gregorian_date(eseconds):
    # Algorithm parameters for Gregorian calendar
    y = 4716; j = 1401; m = 2; n = 12; r = 4; p = 1461 
    v = 3; u = 5; s = 153; w = 2; B = 274277; C = -38

    #Julian day, rounded
    J = int(0.5 + eseconds / 86400.0 + 2440587.5)

    #Date calculation
    f = J + j + (((4 * J + B) // 146097) * 3) // 4 + C
    e = r * f + v
    g = (e % p) // r
    h = u * g + w
    D = (h % s) // u + 1
    M = (h // s + m) % n + 1
    Y = (e // p) - y + (n + m - M) // n

    #Time calculation
    seconds = eseconds % 86400
    t = int(seconds)
    hr, t = divmod(t, 3600)
    mn = t // 60
    seconds -= 3600 * hr + 60 * mn

    return Y, M, D, hr, mn, seconds

# Tests
def test(s):
    t = gmtime(s)
    gmdate = t.tm_year, t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec
    e2gdate = epoch_seconds_to_gregorian_date(s)
    assert gmdate == e2gdate, (s, gmdate, e2gdate)
    return '%d.%02d.%02d %02d:%02d:%06.3f' % e2gdate

print 'now'
s = time()
print s, epoch_seconds_to_gregorian_date(s), gmtime(s)

print '\nhours'
for i in xrange(25):
    s = 3600 * i
    print i, test(s) 

print '\ndays'
for i in xrange(32):
    s = 86400 * i
    print i, test(s)

print '\n2 days by seconds...'
for i in xrange(86400 * 2):
    test(i)
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        sys.stderr.write('.')
sys.stderr.write('\n')

n = 50
print '\n%d years by days...' % n
for i in xrange(365 * n):
    s = 86400 * i    
    test(s)    

n = 500000
print '\nRandom seconds'
for i in xrange(n):
    s = randint(0, 2147483647)
    test(s)
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        sys.stderr.write('.')
sys.stderr.write('\n')

print 'Ok'
```

**output**

```
now
1457355412.48 (2016, 3, 7, 12, 56, 52.476011991500854) time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=12, tm_min=56, tm_sec=52, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=67, tm_isdst=0)

hours
0 1970.01.01 00:00:00.000
1 1970.01.01 01:00:00.000
2 1970.01.01 02:00:00.000
3 1970.01.01 03:00:00.000
4 1970.01.01 04:00:00.000
5 1970.01.01 05:00:00.000
6 1970.01.01 06:00:00.000
7 1970.01.01 07:00:00.000
8 1970.01.01 08:00:00.000
9 1970.01.01 09:00:00.000
10 1970.01.01 10:00:00.000
11 1970.01.01 11:00:00.000
12 1970.01.01 12:00:00.000
13 1970.01.01 13:00:00.000
14 1970.01.01 14:00:00.000
15 1970.01.01 15:00:00.000
16 1970.01.01 16:00:00.000
17 1970.01.01 17:00:00.000
18 1970.01.01 18:00:00.000
19 1970.01.01 19:00:00.000
20 1970.01.01 20:00:00.000
21 1970.01.01 21:00:00.000
22 1970.01.01 22:00:00.000
23 1970.01.01 23:00:00.000
24 1970.01.02 00:00:00.000

days
0 1970.01.01 00:00:00.000
1 1970.01.02 00:00:00.000
2 1970.01.03 00:00:00.000
3 1970.01.04 00:00:00.000
4 1970.01.05 00:00:00.000
5 1970.01.06 00:00:00.000
6 1970.01.07 00:00:00.000
7 1970.01.08 00:00:00.000
8 1970.01.09 00:00:00.000
9 1970.01.10 00:00:00.000
10 1970.01.11 00:00:00.000
11 1970.01.12 00:00:00.000
12 1970.01.13 00:00:00.000
13 1970.01.14 00:00:00.000
14 1970.01.15 00:00:00.000
15 1970.01.16 00:00:00.000
16 1970.01.17 00:00:00.000
17 1970.01.18 00:00:00.000
18 1970.01.19 00:00:00.000
19 1970.01.20 00:00:00.000
20 1970.01.21 00:00:00.000
21 1970.01.22 00:00:00.000
22 1970.01.23 00:00:00.000
23 1970.01.24 00:00:00.000
24 1970.01.25 00:00:00.000
25 1970.01.26 00:00:00.000
26 1970.01.27 00:00:00.000
27 1970.01.28 00:00:00.000
28 1970.01.29 00:00:00.000
29 1970.01.30 00:00:00.000
30 1970.01.31 00:00:00.000
31 1970.02.01 00:00:00.000

2 days by seconds...
..................

50 years by days...

Random seconds
..................................................
Ok
```

Comment: I have run today(07.03.2016) epoch_seconds_to_gregorian_date(time()) and result is (62650,3,11) :)...

Comment: @lalamer: I don't know what you're doing wrong. I just did `s = time();print s, epoch_seconds_to_gregorian_date(s), gmtime(s)` and got this result: `1457347949.53 (2016, 3, 7) time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=10, tm_min=52, tm_sec=29, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=67, tm_isdst=0)`

Comment: PM 2Ring:) I was actually calling time.time() :) It was probably a typo. Now it's showing the date correctly. Thanks. How to get the hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: Yes. Just for completeness, though the question asks only for the month and I know already how to find the time, but it may be helpful for other people.

Comment: @lalamer: Sure. That was my thought as well.

Answer (score 3):

To get the current date:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.today()
```

For the current month:

```
print d.month
```

For a full date:

```
print d.isoformat() // yields '2016-03-04T15:08:04.145000'
```

Answer (score 1):

the `time` module is based on a relative time since the epoch.

To get the current date, you should use the `datetime` module :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects

To complete:

```
import datetime
today=datetime.datetime.now()
month=today.month()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `datetime` to get human readable times.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.now()
print a.month
3
```

Your example fails since you have several years (some of which leap years) with different number of days per month. That will at some point be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

`time.time()` does not return the number of seconds since the beginning of the year; it returns the number of seconds since the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  To get the current day of the month using the `time` module, do this:

```
month = time.localtime().tm_month
```

There is another library for dates, however, called [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).  To get the month from that, do this:

```
month = datetime.today().month
```